# communication between two channels in asterisk

Tags: agi

I am new to asterisk, My task is to establish communication between two applications.I have done it successfully on PRI line both the applications are communicating with each other on different channels. Now I need to control both the applications(i.e communication between two channels), AGI methods are useful to set variables in a channel. as my requirement is to communicate between two channels, per channel variable is no way helpful, Please suggest me any methods in AGI that would be helpful for setting variable per call.

In a call the data should be shared by two variables

Answer (score 0):

please fallow the link this is your answer and try the channels communication in SIP http://www.asteriskguru.com/tutorials/wildcard_tdm400p.html